# How does Al-Hg react with carbonyl in presence of concentrated HCl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-reduction

In Clemmensen reduction, $\ce{Zn-Hg}$/ $\ce{ conc. HCl}$ reduces the carbonyl $\ce{>C=O}$ to $\ce{>CH2}$, by the following mechanism(?):
[image: Clemmensen Reduction Mechanism]

What happens to the carbonyl group if we replace Zinc with any other metal such as Al or Na?

[image]

Will this reaction take place if X is $\ce{Al-Hg / conc. HCl}$ ?

Comment: A more interesting reaction to explore is first react a sheet of Al in HCl. Extract the Al sheet which now holds (for a limited time) H chemisorbed hydrogen. The latter .H surface radical acts per the reaction: H+ + e- = .H, as working with an e- followed by H+. For example, with PbS + 2 .H -> Pb + H2S. That is, Pb2+ + 2 e- = Pb and S(2-) + 2H+ = H2S. Depending on the organic exposed to the Al sheet, expect a variation of the inorganic chemistry which may (or may not) display particular selectivity to produce one or more products.  The example I cited comes from application in Hydrometallurgy.

Comment: Alluded to source reference: 'Hydrometallurgy 2008: Proceedings of the Sixth International Symposium', p. 818, a commercial reductive leaching equation, to quote:
 
" PbS + 2 •H = Pb + H2S (5) "  (see https://books.google.com/books?id=1etfSdk55SYC&pg=PA818&lpg=PA818&dq=what+metals+react+with+hcl+to+form+nascent+hydrogen&source=bl&ots=yEBZaIFL_T&sig=9383ZW7NCXAoSNmmny2sdrxXIF0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEjpnWjejaAhVP4VMKHe1gBZE4FBDoAQg6MAU#v=onepage&q=what%20metals%20react%20with%20hcl%20to%20form%20nascent%20hydrogen&f=false ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In comparision to Clemmensen reduction, **both $\ce{Na-Hg}$ and $\ce{Al-Hg}$ cannot be used as direct substitutes for $\ce{Zn-Hg}$**.

#### Reaction with $\ce{Na-Hg}$ amalgam:

$\ce{Na-Hg}$ amalgam is also a good reducing agent and is capable of reducing ketones/aldehydes to alcohols<sup>1</sup>. However, **Do not use conc. $\ce{HCl}$ with $\ce{Na-Hg}$ amalgam**, as there would be a vigorous reaction between the acid and the sodium in the amalgam. Instead, use an organic solvent such as absolute alcohol.

The mechanism for this reduction is a bit different than standard Clemmensen reduction:

> \begin{align}
> \ce{2(C6H5)2CO +2Na &->2(C6H5)2C-ONa} \\
> \ce{2(C6H5)2C-ONa&<=>(C6H5)2C(ONa)-C(C6H5)2-ONa\tag{1}} \\
> \ce{2(C6H5)2C-ONa + 2C2H5OH &-> 2(C6H5)2C-OH + 2C2H5ONa} \tag{2a} \\
> \ce{2(C6H5)2CO &-> (C6H5)2CO +(C6H5)2CHOH \tag{2b}}
> \end{align}

#### Reaction with $\ce{Al-Hg}$ amalgam:

Aluminium amalgam, like Sodium amalgam, vigorously reacts with water, and you cannot use concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ with it. With ethanol as a solvent, it is a mild reducing agent, can reduce cycloalkanones and aldehydes to alcohols. Acyclic ketones remain almost inert<sup>2</sup>

> [image]

In some cases, it behaves similarily to $\ce{Mg-Hg}$ amalgam and promotes dimerization of ketones to form pinacols. Thus, your reaction would not take place, and instead pinacol would be the major product.

> [image]

[This question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37152/how-does-aluminium-amalgam-work-as-a-reducing-agent) and [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/reaction-mechanism-of-imine-reduction-to-amine-using-an-aluminium-amalgam) cover some other reduction uses of $\ce{Al-Hg}$, such as reduction of imines to amines.

#### References:

1. Bachmann, W. E. “The Mechanism of Reduction by Sodium Amalgam and Alcohol. I. The Reduction of Aromatic Ketones to Hydrols.” Journal of the American Chemical Society, vol. 55, no. 2, **Feb. 1933**, *pp. 770–74*. doi:[10.1021/ja01329a051](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01329a051).
2. Troyansky, Emmanuil I., and Meghan Baker. “Aluminum Amalgam.” Encyclopedia of Reagents for Organic Synthesis, John Wiley & Sons, Ltd, **2016**, *pp. 1–6*. doi:[10.1002/047084289X.ra076.pub2](https://doi.org/10.1002/047084289X.ra076.pub2).